# Replace first part of a Java Path

Tags: java

In Java, I'm looking for a solution to replace the first part of a Path by another.

The only solution I found is a bit ugly, you can find it in the method `subPath` below :

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class TestPath {

    static Path subPath(Path newPrefix, Path pathWithOldPrefix){ ;
        Path result;
        if(pathWithOldPrefix.getNameCount() > 1) {
            result = newPrefix.resolve(pathWithOldPrefix.subpath(1, pathWithOldPrefix.getNameCount()));
        }else{
            result = newPrefix;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //display "/newPrefix/myPath"
        System.out.println(subPath(Paths.get("/newPrefix"), Paths.get("/oldPrefix/myPath")));

        //display "/newPrefix
        System.out.println(subPath(Paths.get("/newPrefix"), Paths.get("/oldPrefix/")));

    }
}
```

Any proposal for a better solution ?

Comment: `Path.relativize`. Just look into the entire javadoc of Path.

Comment: Could you detail a bit ? I want to convert "/oldPrefix/myPath" in "/newPrefix/myPath", I don't see in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize-java.nio.file.Path- how this method can help me.

Answer (score 3):

```
Path pathWithOldPrefix = Paths.get("/oldPrefix/myPath");
Path oldPrefix = Paths.get("/oldPrefix"); // Or maybe
Path oldPrefix = pathWithOldPrefix.subpath(0, 1);
Path newPrefix = Paths.get("/newPrefix");

Path relative = oldPrefix.relativize(pathWithOldPrefix); // myPath
Path newPath = newPrefix.resolve(relative);              // /newPrefix/myPath
Path newPath2 = newPrefix.resolve(oldPrefix.relativize(pathWithOldPrefix));
                                                         // /newPrefix/myPath
```

So `relativize` removes the oldPrefix (note the order of arguments).
And `resolve` adds to then Prefix.

Comment: Hi, I can't accept your answer because the solution with pathWithOldPrefix.subpath(0, 1) is not working. I've got the exception "'other' is different type of Path".

Comment: The only solution I found is to use : 
Path oldPrefix = Paths.get("/"+pathWithOldPrefix.subpath(0, 1));

Comment: @JérômeB no problem, do not need points. Sorry it did not work. Let's move on as you yourself found a solution. Please answer your own question so no loose answer is kept unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Joop Eggen to help me find the right solution, it's not perfect, but it's a better use of Path :

```
public class TestPath {
    static Path subPath(Path newPrefix, Path pathWithOldPrefix){ ;
        Path oldPrefix = pathWithOldPrefix.getRoot().resolve(pathWithOldPrefix.subpath(0, 1));
        Path relative = oldPrefix.relativize(pathWithOldPrefix);
        return newPrefix.resolve(relative);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //display "/newPrefix/myPath"
        System.out.println(subPath(Paths.get("/newPrefix"), Paths.get("/oldPrefix/myPath")));
        //display "/newPrefix
        System.out.println(subPath(Paths.get("/newPrefix"), Paths.get("/oldPrefix/")));
    }
}
```